# Need assistance regarding NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an `NSMutableArray` which contains several `NSMutableDictonary`objects. I am using `NSPredicate` to find out that dictionary with specific key exist or not in the array

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys", users.cellNum];
    NSArray *predResult = [[[self appDelegate]mainArray] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    BOOL success = predResult.count == 0;

    if(success) { 
}
```

its working fine but in predResult I am getting the whole object and it will become memory overhead as the size grows with time.

So I just want to know the dictionary with specific key exist in array or not. I don't want to fetch any object using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.

Comment: Is your issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
     NSUInteger rowindex = [[[self appDelegate]mainArray] indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            return [pred evaluateWithObject:obj];
        }];
```

This will return the integer and

```
 if(rowindex==0|| (rowindex>0&&rowindex<[[self appDelegate]mainArray].count)) {
// data found
}
```

If data is found rowindex will be greater than zero and less than array count